# Json não retorna dados do banco de dados Mysql

Tags: php, html, json, pdo

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados **Mysql** que contém 3 campos ( id, nome e modelo) diferente dos outros campos, o modelo de e-mail dados com *tags* **HTML** (estrutura em *longtext*).

Quando executo o código **PHP** para me retornar os dados, não retorna nenhuma informação. quando executo o mesmo *script* em outra tabela, os dados são retornados perfeitamente. acredito que seja os dados com *tags* **HTML** que existe no meu meu modelo.

Abaixo segue todo o meu *script* **PHP**:

```
    <?php

include_once "conexao.php";

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM modelo_email");          
$sql->execute();
while($data = $sql->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){
    $json ["data"] = $data;

}

 echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No select você não esta informando os nomes dos campos da tabela que deseja jogar no array.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("select id, descricao, modelo_email from modelo_email");
```

Aqui você deve usar o fetch e não fetchAll pois no while está esperando trazer uma informação de cada vez e o fetchAll traz um conjunto de array

```
while($data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Você pode usar o fetchAll mas nesse caso recomendo usar com foreach.

Nesta última parte você esta querendo dar um echo fora while e é por isso que esta retornando null. Se você der o echo dentro do while ele será exibido corretamente

```
while($data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       {
             echo $json = $data['descricao'];
             // var_dump($json);
        }
```

Não entendo muito de php, mas dando uma pesquisada na internet, se você quiser exibir o resultado do while fora dele, você pode declarar uma variável como global.

```
foreach($data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $data1)
    {
         $_global= $json = $data1['descricao'];
         // var_dump($json);
    }
       echo $json;
```

Mais como eu disse, não entendo quase nada de PHP, fazem apenas 10 dias que entrei nessa empreitada, então, aconselho a dar uma pesquisada sobre variáveis globais antes de fazer uso delas.

Answer (score 1):

É porque você inverteu as posições ao armazenar a informação na variável.

```
 <?php

include_once "conexao.php";

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM modelo_email");          
$sql->execute();
while($data = $sql->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){

   //Abaixo você cria a variável e armazena o conteúdo do array nela; 
   $json = $data["data"];

}

 echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Ele retorna o valor assim agora "null"

Comment: Tenta exibir só com   echo $json   ou melhor ainda usa o var_dump($json)  pra ver o que está sendo armazenado dentro da variável $json.

Comment: com o var_dump apresenta os dados. mas traz com erro de caracter, estou achando que o erro seria esse.

Comment: array(5) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["nome"]=> string(25) "Carta de Cobran�a Simples" ["modelo"]=> string(1440) "
Prezado (a) Senhor (a)                                                                                                                                                                      

Verificando nossos arquivos, n�o identificamos o pagamento da (s) cota (s) abaixo relacionada (s) .

Tendo em vista a possibilidade de ter ocorrido um problema envolvendo a baixa banc�ria de seu recibo, pedimos a especial gentileza de nos encaminhar c�pia do seu comprovante

Comment: No exemplo que você me mandou, não estou vendo o campo "data" que você esta querendo trazer pra dentro da variável
Pra você trazer o campo ID voce tem que fazer

$json = $data['id'];
$json = $data['nome'];
$json = $data['modelo'];

Basicamente isso significa, $json= (quero que variável $json receba) do resultado do SELECT que esta armazenado no array  $data o campo  [nomedocampo].

Comment: Não estou dizendo que o uso do campo ['data'] esteja incorreto, até porque você poderia ter esse campo 'data' na tabela MODELO_EMAIL como por exemplo para armazenar a data de cadastro.
Para podermos  certificar que esse campo exista, execute um var_dump($data). Mas acredito que o problema é que você possa estrar trazendo um nome de campo que não exista na tua tabela no caso [data].

Comment: Pior que coloquei os dados, mas mesmo assim ele retorna null.. quando dou um var_dump ele me retorna o array completo , com todos os dados que existe na tabela